# log4j - INFO to console and ERRORS to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to redirect all messages with error level to file and messages with info level to console.
Here is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.java.lang.Exception=ALL, java.lang.Exception

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.java.lang.Exception=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.java.lang.Exception.File=\\clientexceptionlog.txt
log4j.appender.java.lang.Exception.MaxFileSize=2048KB
log4j.appender.java.lang.Exception.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.java.lang.Exception.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

But seems like it doesn't work as I expect: clientexceptionlog.txt is always empty. 
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may work with the `Treshold` option. Doing it that way, you can set the `rootLogger` to both, stdout and your file appender (I named it `myAppender` in the following code snippet):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, myAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.myAppender.File=\\clientexceptionlog.txt
log4j.appender.myAppender.MaxFileSize=2048KB
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

What does it do? It sends everything with a loglevel INFO or higher to stdout and myAppender. While stdout will output all (including higher loglevels like WARN and ERROR) the myAppender will filter out everything that is lower than WARN (due to `log4j.appender.myAppender.Threshold=WARN`).

BTW: Don't use `java.lang.Exception` as name for the appender. That may confuse any one reading this configuration (including me!)